# Which sets currently contain pneumatic LEGO equipment?

Tags: technic, sets, pneumatic

When I was younger my dad bought me [5218-1](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=5218-1), a technic-based pneumatics set, which, combined with the old motor system to provide a mini compressor system created quite a bit of entertainment and it got adapted into various other builds, including a sliding pneumatic bank door.
[image]

Now, as far as I can tell, the only kit like this nowadays is the [Lego Education Pneumatics Add-On Set](http://store.legoeducation.co.uk/shops/lego/Product.aspx?partno=9641#xlink), 9641-1, which comes in at around £39.99, for 31 pieces.
[image]

While I could add this to the [Lego Education Simple & Powered Machines Set](http://store.legoeducation.co.uk/shops/lego/Product.aspx?partno=9686#xlink) that's not cheap either, at around £100 for a more reasonable 390 pieces.

Ultimately, is there a list of all the technic (or lego) sets that include pneumatic kits, and, ideally, are any of them still avalible, apart from the ones I've previously listed?

Comment: Lego Educattion/Dacta set are usually overpriced

Comment: @Ambo100, yeah (from working in education) I kinda gathered.

Comment: [BrickSet](http://brickset.com) has a [list of all Pneumatic Technic Sets](http://brickset.com/brickLists/?1586) as well.

Comment: Ooo...cool! I didn't even know that Lego produced pneumatic sets!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the UK shop, there are currently two sets:

The [Unimog U 400](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Mercedes-Benz-Unimog-U-400-8110) [set:8110] which uses the motorised "compressor" to supply the power (as opposed to the manual sprung pump).

[image: Detail of pneumatic elements]

And the [Tractor with Log Loader](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Tractor-with-Log-Loader-8049) [set:8049] which uses the manual pump:

[image: Log Loader detail]

The other sets that look like they have piston arms (such as [set:8043]) are actually using "[linear actuators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_actuator)", which work with an internal screw thread to lift up the piston, powered by Bevel Gears or Universal Joints:

[image: Bevelled Gears to power actuator] [image: Universal Joint to power actuator]

[part:61927c01]

These provide a much finer level of control over the Pneumatic sets, which is probably why they are being used in more and more sets.

The issue with locating the pneumatic sets is that there have been a few subtle changes to the elements over the years, as well as different lengths in various sets, so tracking them reliably isn't easy:

[BrickLink search for Pneumatic Pumps](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&q=pump&catLike=W&catString=159&sortBy=Y&sortAsc=D&catType=P&v=1)

Comment: Looking at the manual, that's quite a set. Probably better value than getting the Pnuematics set, the simple and powered machines set and another motor.

Comment: (I do mean the Unimog U 400).

Comment: @tombull89 I guessed ;)

Comment: Linear actuators seem to be cropping up in recent sets as an alternative to pneumatic pumps. It may be that linear actuators have a finer degree of control as well as reliability. I don't know for sure as I don't own any.

Comment: @Ambo100 Yep, I certainly remember the frustration with moving a crane arm using the pneumatic controls. The arm wouldn't move until you'd built up sufficient pressure, and then would overshoot the mark.

Comment: @Ambo100 From my experience that's exactly what is going on. The LAs provide such fine control that they're pretty spectacular really. Not quite as much fun as the pneumatics though. :-)

Comment: so, how do the "linear actuators" work? Does it take rotational input and change that to linear? As for this picture for [8043 Motorised Excavator](http://www.thetoyshop.com/media/toyshop/products/Lego/Technic/Zoom/425652.jpg) I can't see how they are powered.

Comment: my god, just looked at the build manual for 8043...that's **insane** and brilliant.

Comment: @tombull89 If you take a look with the Zoom feature on the LEGO Shop (http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Motorized-Excavator-8043) you should be able to see the bevelled gears and universal joints seen here: http://www.doodle.co.uk/UserFiles/Image/BevelGears.png http://www.doodle.co.uk/UserFiles/Image/CabArea.png http://www.doodle.co.uk/UserFiles/Image/UniversalJoint.png

Comment: Note that the first image is from the alternative build "Tracked Loader".

Comment: Crikey. I didn't think it was such tiny detail. /me adds 8110 and 8043 to "want" list.

Comment: @tombull89: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kKgXaS84oQ0#t=25s) vending machine concept is powered by a home-made linear actuator. The Linear Actuator bricks sold by LEGO are smaller.

Answer (score 8):

The set that had the most pneumatic cylinders was the Lego Technic Backhoe, with something around 10. Unfortunately, this set is discontinued. You can, however, buy it on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=38937).

[image]

It is, by far, the coolest pneumatic Lego set ever released.

Comment: That, without a doubt, is pure awesome. I'd hope to see a re-release at some point, maybe even it could be fitted with power functions and automatic compressor...granted it would be expensive but my god it would be an awesome kit.

Comment: holy mamma that is one awesome set